# Priority operators in Java

Tags: java, operators

For the next code, what it's z? (Java)

```
int x = 5;
int y = 10;
int z =++x*y--;
```

The order of priority is:  `y--, ++x, *, =`. 
(  https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/  )
Why after run the code, z = 60 ?

Comment: And what did you expect the result to be?

Comment: `++x` evaluates to 6. `y--` evaluates to 10. 6 * 10 is 60. If that's not what you expect, explain why.

Comment: y-- is post decrement which mean it is decremented after taking the value so y will be 10. ++x is pre increment so it is incremented first and taken value so it becomes 6. so 10 times 6 = 60

Comment: `int z =++x*y--;` is equal to `int z = (x+1)*y;y=y-1;` that's why

Comment: Why is this valid question so downvoted? I really don't understand it's trend.

Comment: Ok.. But what is the order for all operations in Java ? Do you see the link?

Comment: @Nikolas OP could really have explain why expect another result than 60. In details, not by saying that y-- should be evaluated first or something, like that would matter.

Comment: Why do you care about the order of operations? They have no effect in this example.

Comment: @kumesana yes they have...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza describe how

Comment: @Lino that page says "In Java, subexpressions are evaluated from left to right".

Comment: @Lino no... It's just that -- operator is applied to y rather than to the multiplication of x and y. That's operator precedence, not order of operations. Operations are evaluated left to right, and that doesn't matter here anyway.

Comment: @kumesana the order of execution matters here. `++x` means `x=x+1` **before** using x. `y--` means `y=y-1`  **after** using `y`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza that's not order of execution, that's meaning of the operator. No matter when you execute ++x, it will give out the same result anyway in this example.

Comment: @kumesana it's `++x`, not  `x++`, and that **matters** for this case...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza okay, but same reasoning, same effects.

Comment: @kumesana it's not, that's why the output is 60 and not 50.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I meant about the fact that the order of operation doesn't matter in this example, not about whether the final result will be 60 or something else.

Comment: @kumesana but the order of operation matters because that acts directly on the output...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza what output? Here the only output we have is the computed value of the expression. Order of operations change nothing to it.

Answer (score 0):

The ++ operator is evaluated before the expression.

i.e.:

```
int x = 10;
int y = ++x; //y = 11
int z = x ++; // z = 11;
```

Comment: Comments have  point out the reason,so I think you had better avoid to answer question like this,due to someone might downvote it.

Comment: The `++<variable>` operator is evaluated first, while `<variable>++` is evaluated *later*.

Answer (score 0):

`y--` is higher up on the list from your source. However, when the post-decrement happens, it happens *after* the whole evaluation.

So if you print `y` after getting the value of `z`, it will be 9.

And the pre-increment happens first, so `++x` becomes 6 within that statement (and obviously multiplies by 10).

See an [example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) in the docs.